# Laravel Carbon как проверить прошла ли дата

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Сравниваю строку формата 2020-05-17 с текущей датой но результат не верный.
     public static  function endDate($date){

```
    if(Carbon::parse($date)->format("d.m.y")<Carbon::now()){
        return false;//срок не оконен
    }
    else{
      return  true;//дата завершена
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем вы строку сравниваете с датой? Ну это прям как `"яблоки" < 10`

Comment: я же преобразовал в carbon

Comment: Нет. Вы преобразовали в строку методом `format()`

Comment: а надо было как ?

Comment: А надо было сравнивать дату с датой, а не строку с датой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы строку сравниваете с объектом. Это некорректно.

Можно исправить, сделав так:

```
function endDate(string $date): bool
{
    if (Carbon::parse($date)->getTimestamp() < Carbon::now()->getTimestamp()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Тут мы сравниваем timestamp дат, который является int значением.

---

Можно упростить до:

```
function endDate(string $date): bool
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->getTimestamp() > Carbon::now()->getTimestamp();
}
```

---

Можно еще упростить до:

```
function endDate(string $date): bool
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->greaterThan(Carbon::now());
}
```

---

И еще можно упростить до:

```
function endDate(string $date): bool
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->isPast();
}
```